# Connection Test

Tags: testing, performance-testing, software-quality, manual-testing

How can I test the **net-connectivity** of app in performance?

I want to Test the **net-connectivity** range of the app in performance. For example, if the **connection scale is 3G** in some regions, the behavioral changes may happen in the connection depending on the **speed of the internet**.

So how can I test the behaviour of my application under such circumstances?

Comment: Sounds like a job for JMeter. Pretty sure you can simulate different bandwidth options but might be tricky to setup. Haven't done it in a great while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try the JMeter @Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do some form of an ad-hoc testing it can be simulated using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

[image]

If you want to assess your web application performance under the load you could consider using a load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), it is possible to throttle JMeter to simulate slow networks like 3G by manipulating [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) in particular:

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps
httpclient.socket.https.cps
```

[image]

More information: [Controlling Bandwidth in JMeter to simulate different networks](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/Controlling+Bandwidth+in+JMeter+to+simulate+different+networks)